# Is it possible to use API versioning for specific methods within a controller in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm using the API versioning methods provided by Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning (v4.1).
So in the startup class I have the following:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddControllers();

  services.AddMvc(options => options.Filters.Add<ExceptionFilter>());

  services.AddApiVersioning(options =>
  {
      options.ApiVersionReader = new MyCustomVersionReader(configuration);
      options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = false;
      options.ReportApiVersions = true;
      options.ApiVersionSelector = new CurrentImplementationApiVersionSelector(options);
  });            
}
```

In the controller I can then add annotation [ApiVersion("1.0")] to the controller or individual methods.

```
[HttpGet]
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get() {...}
```

Using this, all calls to the api have to have version info in the request header.

However, is it possible to have a specific method within the controller not require a version?

e.g.

```
[HttpGet]
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Method1() {...} //requires version in header

[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Method2() {...} //does not require version in header
```

When I try the above (omitting the ApiVersion annotation for Method2) I still get the following error:

'An API version is required, but was not specified.'

Thank you for helping!

Comment: Set `options.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);`  in `AddApiVersioning` definition.

Comment: Would't this mean that versioning becomes optional? The idea is to have methods where the version info is mandatory, and one where versioning is not needed.

Comment: It's add the versioning to all Actions. Where attribute is not defined on (action or contoller) then the version will be considered as default to 1.0. If specified then the specified attribute value will be used.

Comment: not requiring a version means that we can understand its version as a default of any value (actually meaningless). So in this case I think using a default version of `1.0` is fine. However there may be some other way to deal with by playing around with the versioning extension package. I've not used it yet so not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use `[ApiVersionNeutral]` attribute.You can see my demo below.

First in your startup add:

```
 options.Conventions.Controller<HomeV1Controller>().HasApiVersion(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiVersion(1, 0));
```

Then in your `HomeV1Controller`:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class HomeV1Controller : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("get")]
    public string Get() => "Ok1";

    [HttpGet("getv2")]
    [ApiVersionNeutral]
    public string GetV2() => "Ok2";
}
```

Test result:
[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks! This works perfectly. I didn't know about this attribute.